# looking for a way to allow users to backup the plugin db data(save as)

Tags: wpdb, sql

I have a custom build plugin and I want to add the option to let the user save the plugin data(not using a thirdparty plugin to do this for me).

So if a user clicks on the button it will allow them to save the file as(dont want to save the file to a folder). Has WP a function for this or need I use a custom made function?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

WP has [Filesystem API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) to write files.

However it can be relatively convoluted to implement (since it handles fallback for many cases and environments and workflow for requesting FTP crednetials from users) so often simply PHP functions are used to write file. Works reliably when constrained to uploads folder, otherwise need to be sure about environment or use Filesystem API.

Comment: Okay well I cant use this as I am still a noob, so I need something easy to use ;-)